# jQuery: wrap a div around p not:first elements inside a div

Tags: jquery, html

I've been trying to get my head around this, but can't seem to think straight anymore.
I have a structure like this:

```
<div id="team-101">
   <p>Description 1</p>
   <p>Description 2</p>
   <p>Description 3</p>
   <p>Description 4</p>
   <ul><li>Some stuff</li></ul>
</div>
<div id="team-202">
   <p>Description 1</p>
   <p>Description 2</p>
   <p>Description 3</p>
   <p>Description 4</p>
   <ul><li>Some stuff</li></ul>
</div>
```

(etc.)
What I'd like to do is put the second to last text paragraphs into a div that I could then hide/unhide within each main div:

```
<div id="team-101">
   <p>Description 1</p>
   <div id="desc-101">
      <p>Description 2</p>
      <p>Description 3</p>
      <p>Description 4</p>
   </div>
   <ul><li>Some stuff</li></ul>
</div>
```

I tried something along

```
$('div[id^=team-]').each(function() {
    $('p:first', this).after('<div>');
    $('p:last', this).after('</div>');
```

but the opening div is then closed automatically, and does not contain the following paragraph.
This is probably childrens play, and I'm just too dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the paragraphs, exclude the first one, and wrap them all with `wrapAll`

```
$('div[id^=team-]').each(function() {
    $('p:not(:first)', this).wrapAll('<div id="'+this.id.replace('team','desc')+'" />')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aZu49/2/)

Comment: upvoted this as its the best, but using context? kind of old school.

Answer (score 3):

DOM doesn't work that way, you can't insert opening and closing tags separately, you can select the `p` children and wrap all of them with a DIV element using `.wrapAll()` method:

```
$('div[id^=team-]').each(function() {
    var n = this.id.replace('team-', '');
    $(this).children('p').slice(1).wrapAll('<div id="desc-'+n+'"/>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D7QMe/